# How to get bigger size pictures if me/home items in facebook sdk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Now i'm using Facebook SDK on my ASP.NET MVC5 project, and for data query I use Graph Api.

When I read a data from "me/home", almost each read item of it have key called "picture", that represents image attached to post. But it is thumnbail size, how can I get it bigger resolution and better quality?

Link i got look smth like this:

> [https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/1902827_682459971849744_3936731463452030828_n.jpg?oh=a31397c18fc806dcd1b60565009fd50b&oe=54BAA327&**gda**=1420888048_5c40d0ab0d0b0f5636d7965138f7f6ab](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/1902827_682459971849744_3936731463452030828_n.jpg?oh=a31397c18fc806dcd1b60565009fd50b&oe=54BAA327&__gda__=1420888048_5c40d0ab0d0b0f5636d7965138f7f6ab)

I hope for your help.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable in the API "type" using that you can specify the sizes of the image

The type parameter can be one of square, small, normal, or large for profile pictures or thumbnail, normal, album for album pictures.

image src would be something like this 
https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture?access_token=yyy**&type=normal**

you can find more information @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

```
string imageUrl = fb.Get("/me?fields=picture.type(large)").ToString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.